# MySQL Stored Procedure variable

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mamp

I am trying to make a stored procedure for a MySQL database. The stored procedure is supposed to grab the amount of money each employee has spent on a specific items for lunch. The issue that I am running into is that I cannot get the stored procedure to return any values. When I run it as a SQL query and input a date where my variable is supposed to be it works fine. I am using MySQL. Here is my stored procedure:

```
 DELIMITER $$ 

 CREATE PROCEDURE `class`.`PricePaid`(varBeginningDate DATE) 

 BEGIN

SELECT Item_Desc, SUM( Item_Price ) AS  'Total Price Paid'
FROM Lunch, Item, Lunch_item
WHERE Lunch.Lunch_id = Lunch_item.Lunch_id
AND Item.Item_Number = Lunch_item.Item_Number
AND DATEDIFF(Lunch.Lunch_Date, "'" + varBeginningDate + "'") > 0
GROUP BY Item.Item_Desc;

END
```

My php code calling the function is this

```
<?php

include("Functions.php");

if(isset($_POST['SubmitPricePaid'])){
$strSQL = "CALL `class`.`PricePaid`('{$_POST[$PricePaidDate]}');";
}
?>

<?php if(isset($_POST['SubmitPricePaid'])){ 
        print_report($strSQL, $db); 
      }
?>
```

Comment: May not fix your problem but I remember seeing a similar post a few weeks ago with just that `DELIMITER $$` and the last line of code contained `$$` and it's not present in your code. May be the issue.

Comment: I think you need to use this `END $$` and `DELIMITER;` in 2 lines

Comment: If I add the $$ to the stored procedure I receive this error message: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '$$' at line 12

EDIT: I added the `DELIMITER;` and its giving me the same error

Comment: I pulled that info off of this page http://www.joeyrivera.com/2009/using-mysql-stored-procedures-with-php-mysqlmysqlipdo/ as to why it's giving you an error now, might lie elsewhere.

Comment: So whats your problem....you can't create the stored procedure on the mysql console, or you can't call it from php, or doesn't return a result on your php code ??...

Comment: @RobertRozas I can create the procedure in the MySQL but when I call it I get: Error in query: 'CALL `class`.`PricePaid`('');'

I added my php code to the OP

Comment: are you ussing mysql extension, like this:  $result = mysql_query("call usp_CuentaCartas()"); ??

Comment: @RobertRozas Negative. I'm using it to print the table to the webpage. I added more code above I know the print report function works.

Comment: So in Functions.php you have the print_report func and the value of $db defined, right?

Answer (score 0):

Lets begin with the debugging:

```
<?php

include("Functions.php");

if(isset($_POST['SubmitPricePaid'])){
$strSQL = "CALL `class`.`PricePaid`('{$_POST[$PricePaidDate]}');";
var_dump($strSQL);
var_dump($db);
exit(); //EDITED
print_report($strSQL, $db); 
}

?>
```

Can you post the results of var_dump...i need to see those results

Comment: I get the column headings of Item_Desc Total Price Paid and no data underneath. Unless I need to be looking somewhere specific for the dumps

Comment: The var dump as requested: string(29) "CALL `class`.`PricePaid`('');" resource(1) of type (mysql link)

Comment: I added the var dumps